# Unexplained +1 rep

Tags: support

Every so often I have been getting random +1, or +2 rep bonuses. I'm not sure what they're from.

Is it possible I was reimbursed the points after an answer I downvoted was deleted?

Comment: Yeah, that's usually what it is. Also, posts of yours which have received downvotes, but which were deleted or undownvoted.

Comment: If you look at your reputation tab, at the very bottom there is a checkbox labelled "show removed posts" - check it and it may very well become clear where the rep came from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens if you have downvoted an answer and the answer gets removed (either through the author or moderation).

Downvoting on an answer costs 1 Rep and this reputation is refunded if the answer gets deleted/removed. Your Voting stats will still count though, so if you downvote something and you gain the reputation back, your profile will still show that you have cast a downvote.